# Possible to draw to canvas element in a dynamically created document?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I'm writing some javascript for a Windows 8 app.  I'm trying to render a drawing to a canvas element that is a child of a dynamically created document.

I've got this function returning a new document:

```
        initPrintDoc: function () {

        var emptyDoc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null),
            emptyBody = document.createElement('body'),
            emptyCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            debugDiv = document.createElement('div'),
            debugMsg = document.createTextNode("[PRINT] : This is a test print source.");

        //Initialize attributes for elements
        emptyBody.setAttribute('id', 'pdf-container');
        emptyCanvas.setAttribute('id', 'render-output');
        debugDiv.setAttribute('id', 'debug-output');

        debugDiv.appendChild(debugMsg);
        emptyBody.appendChild(debugDiv);
        emptyBody.appendChild(emptyCanvas);
        emptyDoc.documentElement.appendChild(emptyBody);

        return emptyDoc;

    },
```

The returned document object is not the document object that is displayed in the Windows 8 App UI at runtime.  I am using this dynamically created document as the parameter for the [MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh831251.aspx).  Unfortunately, no matter what I do to the canvas element that is inside this document,  the canvas never shows a rendering in the actual printout, nor in the simple preview window found in the charms bar after clicking a selected printer.

My question is: does a canvas element require its container document to be displayed in the browser window?  Can  you manipulate a canvas element in a dynamically created document, and expect those manipulations to show when you display that document?

Comment: Have you added values to the "width" and "height" attributes of the "canvas" element? It wont render anything without knowing how big it is.

Comment: Yes.  The width and height are set.